# Use Directive scope in Controller

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I built a directive that has checkboxes next to labels, inside a jQuery UI Accordion:

```
    <ul class="checkbox-grid  employee-info-tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="column in columnsData">
            <div class="styleAvailableColumns">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.Selected" />
                <label class="list-columns">{{ column.ColumnDisplayName }}</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

In my **Controller**, I want to be able to save the selected choices the user makes inside the directive, but I'm not sure how.

Here's my directive:

```
angular.module('component.column', [])
.directive('uiAccordion', function ($timeout, Columns, $location) {
    return {
        scope: {
            columnsData: '=uiAccordion'
        },
        templateUrl: '/scripts/app/directives/test.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var generateAccordion = function () {
                $timeout(function () {   
                    $(element).accordion({
                        header: "> div > h3",
                        collapsible: true,
                        active: 'none'
                    });
                });
            }

        var loc = $location.absUrl();
        var reportId = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        Columns.getAll(reportId).then(function (data) {
            scope.columnsData = data;
            generateAccordion();
        }
```

Here's how I use the directive in my view `<div ui-accordion="accordionData"></div>`

I tried using `scope: { '=' }` but got `Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'uiAccordion' is non-assignable!`.

I've done some other googling, but I'm not 100% on the 'correct' direction on how to get this accomplished. If I can provide any other information, please let me know.

Comment: The error means that you used the value `undefined` in a two-way binding. The problem isn't shown in your code or templates. We need to see where you used the `uiAccordion` directive in a template.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Edited my question. Hope that helps

Comment: @MarkC. Can you post your controller code? especially where you are declaring/using accordionData

Comment: @mxa055 That's actually all of the relevant code I have for this. I load the Columns, and the rest works. I am currently not interactive with the Controller at all yet. That's what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your directive scope to:

```
    scope: {
        columnsData: '='
    },
```

Since you want the controller to maintain that data, your controller should have a reference to `$scope.columnsData`.

Then, on the view which is using the controller, you can feed that into the directive like so:

```
<div ui-accordion columns-data="columnsData"> </div>
```

Here's an example of your controller:

```
angular
  .module('...')
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.columnsData = "abcd123"
  }]);
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying, but how does the data get into that variable in my controller?

Comment: '=' tells the isolate scope to use two-way binding. Changes made in the directive will propagate up to the controller that passed the reference, and vice versa.

Comment: @ZackTanner columnsData: '=uiAccordion' means bind whatever is set on ui-accordion attribute to a variable called columnsData not the other way around

Comment: @mxa055 I'm not sure what part of my response you are referring to. '=' refers to a two-way model binding.

Comment: @ZackTanner _Or if you want to use the scope you originally posted, your controller's scope would need $scope.uiAccordion and you would instantiate your directive like so:

<div ui-accordion columns-data="uiAccordion"> </div>_ it should be `<div ui-accordion="uiAccordion"></div>`

Comment: So, the data is inside of my directive - not my controller. I load the data inside of the directive as well, not in the controller. (`Columns.getAll()`)

Comment: In any case, the controller will be updated with that data.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Still new to the linking aspect of directives. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try using your directive as:

```
<div ui-accordion="controllersColumnsData"></div>
```

where controllersColumnsData is a collection you can iterate in your controller whose items will have ColumnDisplayName and Selected properties set from your directive.

Comment: So, `controllersColumnsData` is just a variable in my Controller? But I load the data inside of the directive.

Comment: Yes and though two way binding, this data will be "automagically" be available in your controller as well. That's what '=' is for.